# Solve $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + \omega^2 u = \sin(\lambda t)$ by using the following algorithm...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + \omega^2 u = \sin(\lambda t)$$
By using the following integral to create the particular solution $Y_P$ like this...
$$Y_P = \int_0^t G(t-s) f(s) ds$$ where $$G(t) = \int_0^t e^{\alpha (t-s)} e^{\beta s} ds$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the auxillary equation of the homogenous form of the D.E. above.

I'm totally stuck because I only know how to solve by using undetermined coeff. or variation of parameters methods.

What is this solving algorithm and how to solve by using it????

Comment: I fear you should know Dirac's $\delta$. Is it in your knowledge baggage?

Comment: What about Laplace or Fourier transform?

Comment: @Jon I know only the basics of o.d.e. solving because my prof taught me in Calculus 2. What is Dirac delta fn. anyway?

Comment: This is a simple linear system with input $sin(\lambda t)$ and output $u(t)$. The input-output relation of Linear systems are completely determined by their Impulse Response $h(t)$, the output of the system to impulse input $\delta (t)$. Once you know $h(t)$, then the output of the system to arbitrary input is the convolution of the input with $h(t)$. The formula you wrote is just the convolution of $G(t)$ and $f(t)$, where $G(t)$ is actually the impulse response of your system and $f(t)$ is your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute the proposed solution in the equation as $u$. But before that note that by evaluating the integral:

\begin{equation*}
 G(t) = \frac{e^{\beta t} - e^{\alpha t}}{\beta - \alpha}, \hspace{0.5cm} where \hspace{0.5cm} \beta = j\omega, \alpha = -j\omega
\end{equation*}

Now, if we substitute $u(t) = \int_{0}^{t}G(t-s)f(s)ds$, we need first to find second time derivative of $u$. By leibniz rule:

\begin{equation*}
 \frac{du}{dt} = G(0)f(t) + \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial G(t-s)f(s)}{\partial t}ds = \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\beta e^{\beta (t-s)} - \alpha e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha}f(s)ds 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\beta e^{\beta (t-s)} - \alpha e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha}f(s)ds ) = f(t) + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\beta^2 e^{\beta (t-s)} - \alpha^2 e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha}f(s)ds 
\end{equation*}

Now substituting $\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2}$ in your differential equation, and noting that $\beta = j\omega, \alpha = -j\omega$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + \omega ^2u(t) = f(t) + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\beta^2 e^{\beta (t-s)} - \alpha^2 e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha}f(s)ds + \omega ^2 \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{\beta (t-s)} - e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha}f(s)ds = f(t) + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{(\beta^2 + \omega ^2) e^{\beta (t-s)} - (\alpha^2  + \omega^2) e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha}f(s)ds = sin(\lambda t)
\end{equation*}
Here, as $(\beta^2 + \omega ^2) = (\alpha^2 + \omega ^2) =0$, we have:

\begin{equation*}
f(t) = sin(\lambda t).
\end{equation*}

Then,  your $Y_p$ is:

\begin{equation*}
Y_p = \int_{0}^{t}  \frac{e^{\beta (t-s)} - e^{\alpha (t-s)}}{\beta - \alpha} sin(\lambda s)ds 
\end{equation*}